# Multiple Table Rules

Tags: drools

[XLS Multiple Table Rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/voSR2.png)

I created this xls rules. But when a matched is found, the other rules also fires. That is, if DIV 07 passed, DIV02, DIV N95, Div 8M and OTHERS also fires. Is there a way to which when a condition matches, the rule corresponding to that match is the only one that fires and the rest are ignored?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try keyword - "activation-group"

rule 1 "rule1"
salience 1
activation-group "A"

rule 2 "rule2"
salience 0
activation-group "A"

when firerules (auto run by salience order), if rule1 matched, all rest of the same activation-group(rule 2) would be ignored

Comment: Where/how do I place this "activation-group" in xls? Tian?